# What's the best practice in relationing 2 or more relationship tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a trip (primary: idTrip), where I can link more packages (primary: idPackage), so, I got a relationship table to link trips with packages (primary: idRelTripPackage). (relationship n-to-n)

And next I got a registrations table (primary: idRegistration). How do I best link those (1-to-1 relationship)?

1. I add two columns in the registrations table (idTrip, idPackage)?
2. I add a relationship table where i link idRegistration, idTrip, idPackage?
3. I add a relationship table where i link idRegistration, idRelTripPackage?

Comment: Any chance of progressing the answers, getting votes, choice of answer, etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I right in thinking the relation from Registrations is to RelTripPackage, and its definitely one-to-one. There are a couple of options:

1: As it really is a one-to-one there's not really anything to stop you putting the Registrations data directly onto RelTripPackage, or doing the vice-versa and putting idPackage and idTrip straight onto Registrations as FKs, with a unique key across the two FK columns to ensure there aren't duplicates.

2: If do want the two separate tables then just add idRetTripPackage to Registrations as an FK, and then add a unique constraint on it - again to ensure uniqueness.

There's no need for a separate relationship table as its a 1-1 relationship - They only really become relevant when you are using an n-n. The rest of the time FKs should be placed directly on the child table.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow that logic, you will

- add tables and Relations every time you need to add Relations
- end up with confusing or duplicate Relations (multiple paths between any two tables)

However the problem (limiting factor) is that the tables you are starting with are not actually normalised.  Since the starting position does not have a good basis, you will end up with far more Relations (in tables) than there actually are between the Entities.  So the best advice is, the Best practice is, before you attempt this current extension, step back and normalise the data, the existing tables.  Then the extension will be much easier, and you will end up with less tables.

- if you provide info re the tables (Person, Trip, Package, etc); what exactly is a Registration, etc ... I can provide more explicit answers.

Generally any attribute that is 1::1 with the PK of an Entity should be an attribute in that entity. Any attribute that is 1::0-1 with the PK of an Entity should be in a separate table.

### ER Diagram

Based on the information provided, this is your [**▶Entity Relation Diagram◀**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Bogdan%20ERD%20110305.pdf). As long as you use Relational Identifiers, all the Relations you have identified thus far are supported directly (otherwise, if you use IDs, you will need more Relations and tables).

Readers who are unfamiliar with the Relational Database Modelling standard may find [**▶IDEF1X Notation◀**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) useful.

Comment: well, a registration is a signup (order) from a traveler to take part to a trip, by choosing a package (that he pays).

Comment: @Bogdan.  Ok.  And what is the distinction between Trip and Package ? Is Package a group of Trips or Trip + Airfare + Hotel ? Or is Trip a single full journey and Package the rate (based on quality) that they pay ? Etc.

Comment: packages are the kind of service you can choose for registering (only accomodation, acco + transp, acco + transp + equipment), so.. the trip can have many packages, but the registration can get only 1 trip, and the travelers (thar are associated to the registration) only 1 package for the trip they register to.

Comment: @Bogdan. So a Registration is not "a traveller", it is more than one person ... but only one Package? And if one of the group of travellers belonging to a Registration wants a different Package, they have to get a separate Registration ?  I do not see how Trip::Package is n::m, or why you need a "relation" table to relate them.

Comment: Registration has 1 trip (for the entire group), every traveler (person) gets to choose 1 package from that trip. Don't confuse travelers with registered users. There is no such thing as user registration (login/logout support). (The diagram is incorrect in the sense that the registration gets to choose the package; the registration gets the trip, the traveler in that registration gets the package)

Comment: @Bogdan.  1) Pardon me, but I am not confused ... I am only interpreting the info you have provided, which is not exactly clear.  The clearer you are, the better I can serve you.  2) Registration has one Package; Package has one Trip; therefore Registration has one Trip [read the Notation doc]. 3) I do not have User. Person merely avoids duplication of a Person as a Passenger.  4) I have updated the ERD, to now provide that each Passenger can choose a different Package within the one Registration/Trip.  Registration and Passenger still have only one Trip.

Comment: There is not enough info, the model is too early, to have any confidence in it.  Therefore don't worry about "mistakes", just keep clarifying Entities and Relations, which will lead to a model which can be relied upon ... otherwise everything is a "mistake" until we get there.